# Local-storage didn't store the state of multiple slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, slidetoggle

I want to do a multiple vertical-menu with slideToggle and store the state of the toggle in local-storage, I don't understand why the state isn't stored.

I found this example (https://codepen.io/johnyrodni/pen/VVMXJx) who works, but when I try to past it to my real needs (https://codepen.io/azyme/pen/PrGNpW) there's no more local-storage.

```
<div id="dropdown-1">
        <div class="heading">
      Click me
        </div>

            <ul class="content">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2">
        <div class="heading">
      Click me
        </div>

            <ul class="content">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var openTabs = [];


    $(".content").hide();

    $(".heading").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
        selector = $this.parent().attr('id') + ' .heading';

        if ($(this).next('.content').is(':visible'))
        {
            var pos = openTabs.indexOf(selector);
            openTabs.splice(pos, 1);

        }
        else
        {

            openTabs.push(selector);
        }

        localStorage.openTabs = openTabs.join(',');

        $this.next(".content").slideToggle();

    });

    if (localStorage.openTabs)
        $(localStorage.openTabs).click();
});
```

I expect that the state of the toggles will store in the local-storage

Comment: Your pen shows the `local storage` with correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it.

Replace this line:

```
localStorage.openTabs = openTabs.join(',');
```

with this:

```
localStorage.setItem('openTabs', JSON.stringify(openTabs.join(',')))
```

and this one:

```
if (localStorage.openTabs)
        $(localStorage.openTabs).click();
```

with this:

```
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('openTabs'))
     $(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('openTabs'))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! There one last thing I don't understand : when I reload the page the toggle is always closed even if I've open it before the reload, dis you know from where it could come ?

Comment: Yes, I understand. Just replace this line inside the `if` statement:
`$(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('openTabs'))).click();` with this line:
`$(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('openTabs'))).click().next(".content").slideToggle();`

And please mark the answer "as accepted" if it worked for you! :)

Comment: I did, but it's always the same result. Is this because there is the hide() at begin ? I noticed that if I remove it it still doesn't work..

Comment: in that case, you can store a separate variable in `localStorage` which simply stores whether the toggle was opened (set it as `true`) or closed (`false`) and then using an if statement, you can use `.slideToggle()` to open it or close it

Comment: Thanks alot for your help ! I finally succeed, here's my codepen working well
https://codepen.io/azyme/pen/PrGNpW